# Capturing multicast packets in WLAN

Tags: wireless, monitoring

(I had to move this from Network Engineering stack exchange where I origianlly asked this question)

If a device in monitoring mode snoops on the traffic in a WLAN, can it CAPTURE and READ multicast packets?

For instance, if a device broadcasting packets to multicast address 239.255.255.250, can a monitoring device capture and read those packets?

Comment: You should be able to capture everything which is destined for your system, i.e. multicast converted to unicast or true multicast. For details about this see [Can I truly multicast over WIFI?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/36450/can-i-truly-multicast-over-wifi) over at [networkengineering.se].

Comment: You could do this without monitor or promiscuous mode, assuming the target is in the correct multicast group(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends of that packet is encrypted. If you happen to capture a multicast packet sent over an open WLAN, then you can read it without problems.

If the packet is encrypted, then you need the key in order to read the packet successfully.

The reason why you can in general use multicast, is because of the OSI layer model. It simply does not matter to the higher layers how the lower layers are implemented. As such, if a network uses mixed clients (some wired, some wireless), multicast and broadcast still need to work.